# Fit a distribution to a combinatorial problem

Tags: distributions, probability

In my previous question titled ["Conditional combinations of balls in bowls"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183614/conditional-combinations-of-balls-in-bowls), is there a distribution to fit $k$ when $d \gg M$? I mean, when $d$ is so large, what is the distribution of the total number of balls?

$M$ can be a number between $4$ to $64$ and $d$ (number of bowls) is very large, about $10000$. Each bowl can have $0,1,2,\ldots,M$ balls in it with equal probability. What is the distribution of total number of balls $k$?  $\Pr(k=k_0)=$?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: "...with equal probability" is helpful but ambiguous. Perhaps you could describe the process by which the bowl populations and $k$ are determined?

Comment: @whuber Seems to me that the OP is saying the probability is 1/(M+1) for each number of balls from 0 to M.

Comment: @Michael Yes, but that leaves a huge amount of latitude. Is $k$ fixed in advance? Are there other possible dependencies among the bowl populations?

Comment: @whuber K is a random variable, so it is not fixed.  Although not stated I would assume that each bowl's contents is independent of the others and 0<=k<=dM is the constraint on k.

Comment: @Michael According to the referenced question, "There are $k$ balls...," suggesting $k$ is *not* a random variable. So let's not assume anything and just let the OP clarify his question. There's little point in making up some interpretation that might or might not conform to the original intention.

Comment: @whuber Yes I got confused. It seems that k is fixed and the distribution is for the way the k balls get distributed in the d bowls. But the notation used is confusing because he writes P(k=k$_0$).

Comment: Well, thank you guys, actually K is a random variable. Thank you so much Henry.

Answer (score 1):

Using uppercase $K$ for a random variable and lowercase $m,d,k_0$ for constants:

The number of balls in a particular bowl has a [discrete uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29) with mean $\frac{m}{2}$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{\frac{m^2+2m}{12}}$.

Add up a large number $d$ of these i.i.d. then the the distribution of sum $K$ with mean $\frac{md}{2}$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{\frac{(m^2+2m)d}{12}}$ can be approximated  using the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), remembering $K$ is discrete with integer spacing.

So $$\Pr(K=k_0) \approx \Phi \left( \frac{k_0 +\frac12 -\frac{md}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{(m^2+2m)d}{12}}}  \right)- \Phi \left( \frac{k_0-\frac12 -\frac{md}{2} }{\sqrt{\frac{(m^2+2m)d}{12}}}  \right) \approx \phi \left( \frac{k_0-\frac{md}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{(m^2+2m)d}{12}}}  \right) $$ where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function and $\phi$ is the probability density function of a [standard normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_distribution#Properties).